# How to Make ActiveRecord always update a field?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When using ActiveRecord, if you are updating a record, it only adds the fields that have changed to the query.  I need a way to tell it to always add a particular field to my query, even if Rails doesn't think it changed.  In my example, I always want to set a field to "U" when saving a record.  The name of the field is DELETE_FLAG.  So, I want to see DELETE_FLAG="U" in the UPDATE query that is sent to MySQL every time.

I've tried `DELETE_FLAG_will_change!` In the model, but that doesn't seem to have done anything, perhaps because I put it in the wrong place?

I've seen the `touch` method as well, but this will not do.  I don't want to update the record again afterwards.

This seems so basic, I'm sure I must be overlooking something here.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Even if the value is already correct in the database before the update?  What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: I would like to echo the "why" question. Without knowing why you want to update something that doesn't normally need to be updated we aren't in a good position to give the best way to do so.

Comment: Well, usually "why" means "we don't know" :).  The "why" is because we have a scheduled integration that runs that can change this field on its own.  I need to make sure that every save of an activerecord puts this flag back where it needs to be. Honestly, I don't know if this will fix the problem, but my boss asked me to make it so, and it seems like it should be so simple. I'm just trying to do some debugging, really.  I just need to add this field to the query every time. Thanks

Comment: If it's a model that just got loaded, there won't be any effect to doing this.  You might be better served with a +before_save+ callback (or something similar) that just sets the value to what it "needs" to be.

Comment: have you tried 
`class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base; before_update lambda { self.DELETE_FLAG = "U" };end` 
.. I don't totally get what you're trying to do but hopefully this will get you closer =)

Comment: Abdo, thank you for your suggestion.  I don't fully understand lambdas and procs, and when i put this into my model it failed (because the model is abstract?  it is always extended and doesn't have a direct DB table linked to it